# struggling with python and Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm learning python and Kivy and I'm really struggling to understand how to call functions and continue functions from a Kivy GUI.

Here is my .py:

```
import csv
import os
import easygui
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.7')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

def csvImport(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        your_list = list(reader)
        return your_list

class LoadFile(App):
    def FileLoadScreen(self):
        self.add_widget(Button(size_hint_y=(None), height=('48dp'), text='Select File',
                    on_press=self.ImportFile))

    def ImportFile(self, instance):
        filepath = easygui.fileopenbox()
        if filepath!='.':
            a=csvImport(filepath)
            instance.text='File Loaded'
            instance.disabled=True

class loginBAKApp(App):
    def logAuth(username,password):
        if username!='' and password!='':
            print('ok')
    kv_directory = 'GUI'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loginBAKApp().run()
```

And this is my loginBAK.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.9.0
GridLayout:
    row_force_default: True
    row_default_height: 40
    rows: 3
    cols: 2
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10
    Label:
        id: userLabel
        text: 'Username:'
    TextInput:
        id: username
    Label:
        id: passwordLabel
        text: 'Password:'
    TextInput:
        id: password
        password: True
    Button:
        id:btn_login
        text: 'Login'
        on_press: print('OK')
```

This code seems to work without issues (when I click the login button, it does print 'OK'. I tried to swap it out with

```
on_press: logAuth(username,password)
```

and I get an error that logAuth is not defined.

Ultimately, what I'm trying to model here (as my first learning experience) is to hit the login button and as long as the fields are not blank, display a login success message for 5 seconds and then delete the fields and call the LoadFile app (add a button that can be clicked to select and import a file).

What exactly am I doing wrong here? I've sifted through about 60 scripts online and have been looking at the Kivy examples for hours and I cannot figure out how I'm doing this wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction and/or make suggestions as to creating/deleting the gui to do what I described? I'm new to Kivy (and can code basic python scripts) so this is all a little confusing to when I read some of the other questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

```
on_press: logAuth(username,password)
```

logAuth is a method of your app class, not a function defined in the kv namespace. You can instead use `app.logAuth(...)`, `app` is a keyword that references the current App instance.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I got that part working now, but I'm still struggling to figure out how to delete the elements and call the next function.